# What is the Julia function to count combinations (n choose k)?

Tags: julia, combinatorics, counting

I'm looking for the (hopefully built-in) function in Julia that calculates the number of combinations

[image: nChooseK]

I could obviously implement my own using factorials, but I'm almost certain somebody has already worried about this.

Comment: Minor note: the binomial coefficient counts *combinations*, not permutations.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and the difference is important because you are counting permutations to be the same. I'll edit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Chances are you're looking for the `binomial` function that returns the binomial coefficient. It's currently in [base](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.binomial)

Here are some simple examples:

```
julia> binomial(2,1)
2

julia> binomial(3,2)
3
```

If you want to see the actual combinations, then you can use the `Combinatorics` package's `combinations(a,n)` function. This gives you an iterable with all the possible combinations of length `n` of array `a`.

```
julia> using Combinatorics

julia> collect(combinations(1:3,2))
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]
 [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Be aware to use BigInt if you want to take binomial of "big" numbers like 200

```
julia> binomial(3,2)
3

julia> binomial(300,200)
ERROR: OverflowError: binomial(300, 200) overflows
Stacktrace:
 [1] binomial(::Int64, ::Int64) at ./intfuncs.jl:876
 [2] top-level scope at none:0

julia> binomial(BigInt(300),BigInt(200))
4158251463258564744783383526326405580280466005743648708663033657304756328324008620
```

Comment: `julia> binomial(big"300", 200)
4158251463258564744783383526326405580280466005743648708663033657304756328324008620` also works.